# Saving/Retrieving igraph Graph attributes

Tags: python, attributes, igraph, file-format, read-write

I am trying to save and then retrieve an igraph Graph with the graph attributes.  Specifically, I have a two-terminal graph, and I am storing the source and sink as graph attributes so I can retrieve them in constant time.  Note, the vertices are not in any specific order (e.g., the first vertex is the source and the last is the sink).

I have searched the documentation but I can't see that any of the formats support storing/retrieving graph attributes.  Am I missing anything?

My fallback is to use boolean source/sink vertex attributes, but that takes more space and requires linear time to retrieve the right vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) supports numeric and string attributes that can be attached to the entire graph, to individual vertices or to individual edges (actually, it supports even more complex ones but igraph's GraphML implementation is limited to numeric and string attributes). So, you could use `Graph.write_graphml()` and `Graph.Read_GraphML()`. Also, you can simply save an igraph graph using Python's `pickle` module (i.e. use `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()`) and you will get all the graph/vertex/edge attributes back (even complex Python objects) -- the only catch is that the `pickle` format is not interoperable with other tools outside the Python world.

Comment: Great response.  It put me on the right track.  GraphML wasn't capturing the attributes because I had the attributes point to the vertex objects.  When I tried to pickle, that also gave a TypeError because you "can't pickle Vertex objects." (Not sure why, but anyways...)  So, I resolved it by storing the source/sink indices (i.e., integers) in the graph attribute rather than the vertex objects directly.  Again, good response.